# MySQL replace - manipulate portion of string

Tags: mysql

Inside a mysql table have a column containing relative urls and other urls and I would like to jump the last digit by 10000 (for the relative urls)

```
...
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=220
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=221
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=222
http://somerandomurl.com
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=227
http://anotherrandomurl.com
...
```

I know how to replace fixed portions of strings but I still don't know how to programmatically change parts of the string so that it results in this pattern

```
...
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10220
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10221
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10222
http://somerandomurl.com
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10227
http://anotherrandomurl.com
...


UPDATE url_table
SET url_field = REPLACE ?????????
WHERE url_field LIKE '%index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=%'
```

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this operation?

Comment: Will it always be 3 digits?

Comment: for this particular case yes

Comment: Then posted an answer

Comment: I have realized some links end in ....=22 (that's two digits). I think I will end up using a php script to jump the numbers ... :(

Answer (score 1):

If the number is always 3 digits, then you can use this:

```
UPDATE url_table
SET url_field = replace(url_field,right(url_field,3),right(url_field,3)+10000)
WHERE url_field = LIKE '%index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=%'
```

I'm not sure how mysql deals with a number in string type column so if it doesn't accept it:

```
UPDATE url_table
SET url_field = replace(url_field,right(url_field,3),
                       cast(right(url_field,3) to number) +10000 to string)
WHERE url_field = LIKE '%index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If it always 3 digit from right that need to be inserted then @sagi's answer is correct. But if that is not the case, then you need regular expression. MariaDB since version 10 has [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/) function for replacing string with regular expression. [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) might help if you do not use MariaDB.